# Getting data in Firebase and not a Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that shoudl return a proper object and not promise . I am calling this function which internally calls the Firebase . How can i get the details from firebase snapshot.

```
    function getData(tab){
    
    var data =  getDataSetFromFirebase(tab) ; 
    console.log(data);
    }
    
    
    async function getDataSetFromFirebase(tab){
       var allData = [] ; 
      var  clients = [] ; 
      const q = query(collection(db, '0M0drKmwJCWal7XHjHKuPz3rhHQ2'));
      const querySnapshot  =  await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach(cl => {
        clients.push(cl.data()['company']);
        clients.push(cl.id);
        allData.push(clients);
        clients = [] ;
    })
    const allClientsData = await Promise.resolve(allData);
    return allClientsData; 
    }
```

Comment: try making `getData` function async . you can then awaits for the results to be fetched and use them for your needs .  `const getData = async(type)=> {var data = await getDataSetFromFirebase(tab);}`

Comment: `await Promise.resolve(allData)` seems pointless. Just  `return allData`.